# Working with GUID type : PHP

Tags: php, soap, parameters, guid

I'm working with a SOAP application that asks for some parameters with the type GUID.
I'm not exactly sure what that all means.

I found this for making GUID's in PHP:

```
function getGUID(){
    if (function_exists('com_create_guid')){
        return com_create_guid();
    } else {
        mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);//optional for php 4.2.0 and up.
        $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
        $hyphen = chr(45);// "-"
        $uuid = chr(123)// "{"
            .substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12)
            .chr(125);// "}"
        return $uuid;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how this works when I'm trying to pass in a parameter.
Here is an example of how I need to use it:

```
$option=array('trace'=>1);
$url = "http://example.com/admin.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($url, $option);
$params = array(
    'consumerid'   => '1234',
    'userName'     => '1234',
    'password'     => '1234',
    'adminDomain'  => 'admin.example.com',
    'SubscriberID' => '1234',
    'orderID'      => '22147'); /* <- This value needs to be of the type GUID */

$result = $client->getOrderDetail($params);
```

I can create new GUIDs, but I don't know how to associate a value with it. Can someone offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
$option=array('trace'=>1);
$url = "http://example.com/admin.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($url, $option);

# get guid and store in variable
$guid = getGUID();

$params = array(
    'consumerid'   => '1234',
    'userName'     => '1234',
    'password'     => '1234',
    'adminDomain'  => 'admin.example.com',
    'SubscriberID' => '1234',
    'orderID'      => $guid); # now use that guid here

$result = $client->getOrderDetail($params);
```

Comment: sure, but how do I get the value I'm looking for to go along with that $guid variable? Because when I make a guid and just echo it out, it is different every time.

Comment: @alexthebake: What value are you looking for exactly? The `getGUID` function already returns a different value each time and guid are supposed to be unique.

Comment: okay, well then I'm just confused. Because I need the getOrderDetail method to return the details of the order I specify based on orderID. But if the type for orderID has to be a GUID, then I can never specify the orderID that I want.  Is there some way to attach a value to the guid?

Comment: Can you define `attach a value to guid`? Do you mean concatenating guid with some other value also like `guid+your value` joined ?

Comment: Well the guid is an identifier right? Can that identifier identify a string?

Comment: @alexthebake: Guid is unique bunch of characters, it is itself a string and you can compare one string with another. You may want to search wikipedia for more info about guids